# Como puedo deserializar este JSON polimórfico?

Tags: java, json, deserialize

Tengo problemas para deserializar este JSON:

```
{
  "locations":
  [
    {
      "name": "Sagrada Família",
      "coordinates": [2.174400, 41.403475],
      "description": "Famosa església inacabada iniciada la dècada de 1880, amb un museu i vistes de la ciutat.",
      "architect": "Antoni Gaudí i Cornet",
      "inauguration": 2026
    },
    {
      "name": "Plaça Catalunya",
      "coordinates": [2.170079, 41.386878],
      "description": "La plaça de Catalunya és la més cèntrica i gran de les places de Barcelona. Constitueix el punt d'unió \nentre el nucli antic de la ciutat i l'Eixample. D'aquí parteixen importants vies de la ciutat com la Rambla, \nel passeig de Gràcia, la rambla de Catalunya, les rondes de la Universitat i de Sant Pere i el carrer Pelai, \nigual com l'avinguda del Portal de l'Àngel, la gran artèria comercial de la ciutat, i antiga porta de \nles muralles."
    },
    {
      "name": "Can Punyetes",
      "coordinates": [2.159704, 41.398694],
      "description": "Restaurant de cuina catalana.",
      "characteristics": ["Acollidor", "Informal", "Està bé per als nens"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Traphouse",
      "coordinates": [2.165150, 41.405290],
      "description": "Casa reconeguda principalment per les cançons que es composen aquí. Els veïns són una delícia, \nmai es queixen del xivarri que hi ha."
    },
    {
      "name": "Lloc de Socis",
      "coordinates": [2.166506, 41.402617],
      "description": "Si alguna vegada vols ser soci d'un club on la gent s'ho passa molt bé, aquest és el lloc \non has d'anar. No te'n penediràs!"
    },
    {
      "name": "Adoquín Square",
      "coordinates": [2.172804, 41.388794],
      "description": "Plaça coneguda pels jocs lúdics que s'organitzen. Es poden fer des de partides de Minecraft fins al \njoc de la manguera d'aigua. També s'ofereix servei de barbacoa."
    },
{
      "name":"Hotel W",
      "coordinates": [2.190109, 41.368762],
      "description": "Hotel més famós de Barcelona definit per la seva forma de vela. A dins t'hi pots trobar de tot\n menys Barcelonins. Ha estat galardonat amb el premi per més mites per metre quadrat de la ciutat, \nprecedit per La Salle Campus Barcelona",
      "stars": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Este JSON está compuesto por objetos de la clase `Location`, pero dependiendo de los atributos de cada `Location`, esta podrá pertenecer a una clase `Hotel`, `Monumento` o `Restaurante`.

Las clases que he creado son:

```
public class Location {

    private String name;
    private double[] coordinates;
    private String description;
}

public class Hotel extends Location {

    private short stars;
}

public class Monument extends Location {

    private String architect;
    private short inauguration;
}

public class Restaurant extends Location {

    private String[] characteristics;
}
```

Además he creado una clase llamada `DataModel` que contiene una array de `Location` para poder guardar las diferentes localizaciones polimórficamente:

```
public class DataModel {

    private Location[] locations;
}
```

Esto es lo que hago para leer el JSON, usando RuntimeTypeAdapter:

```
try {
            RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Location> runtimeTypeAdapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
                                                                    .of(Location.class, "locations")
                                                                    .registerSubtype(Hotel.class, "hotel")
                                                                    .registerSubtype(Monument.class, "horse")
                                                                    .registerSubtype(Restaurant.class, "restaurant");
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(runtimeTypeAdapterFactory).create();
            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(path));
            dataModel = gson.fromJson(reader, DataModel.class);

        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
        }
```

Pero como output, el programa lanza una excepción:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonParseException: cannot deserialize class models.Location because it does not define a field named locations

He intentado cambiar el "field name" que lanza el error por "type", como se muestran en algunos ejemplos donde se usa el RuntimeTypeAdapter y tampoco funciona.

¿Qué pasa?

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que generes los "pojos" (clases para mapear el json a java) con esta utilidad online :

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

luego lo importas a tu proyecto las clases que ha generado y lo utilizas como lo está utilizando en esta línea

```
dataModel = gson.fromJson(reader, <aquí pones la clase de partida que le has indicado a la herramienta>);
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si más no me equivoco lo que tiene que hacer es crear un objeto que contenga un atributo `locations` de tipo `List<Location>` algo como

```
public class ResponseLocations{
  private List<Location> locations;

  //Constructor, getters y setters
}
```

Y este es el objeto donde guarda el JSON, Ahora como se comporte con las subclases, eso no lo he hecho.